# Azure function IConfig using dependency injection

Tags: azure, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I need some information from config file, I have this information in my local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "EmailProcessConnection": "",
    "SendDeveloperMails": 0,
    "Email": {
      "Email": "",
      "Password": ""
    },
   
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "HumanRisksDbContext": ""
  }
}
```

I have a service which is being called from my time trigger Azure Function. Its constructor is like this

```
public ControlRisksService(HumanRisksDbContext context, 
    ILogHandler logHandler, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    this.context = context;
    _logHandler = logHandler;
    _config = configuration;
}
```

I need to get information from _config like this later on,

```
_config.GetValue<bool>("SendDeveloperMails")
```

How can I get this information?

Answer (score 0):

You can get information from the `local.settings.json` using `EnvironmentVariable`:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddEnvironmentVariables().Build();
var connString = config["ConnectionStrings"];
```

Also, you need to put the updated `local.settings.json` file into the `D:\MyApp\bin\Debug\net6.0\local.settings.json` location, and then register the JSON in the startup file `program.cs` like below:

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(app =>
    {
        app.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, 
            reloadOnChange: true).AddEnvironmentVariables().Build();
    }).Build();
```